# Need to check file existance in all the subfolders of folder X via window cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to make use of window cmd in my sas script to find a particular file in the given path and all of its subfolders.

I have **fileexist** function to use in sas ,but it requires exact path as input 
e.g : C:\Users\vamehta\Downloads\Vaibhav\Project\abc.txt.

Wheras I need to find whether abc.txt exist in any of the subfolders of 
C:\Users\vamehta\Downloads\Vaibhav\Project.

Kindly help me tackle this. I am looking for  window cmd for this.

Comment: What did you tried, where in the code are the problems(where is your code?), what errors occur?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you would like to use the string in the sas command:

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('dir "C:\Users\vamehta\Downloads\Vaibhav\Project" /b /a-d /s ^| find /i "abc.txt"') do echo %%a
```

or using `where`

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('where /r "C:\Users\vamehta\Downloads\Vaibhav\Project" "abc.txt"') do echo %%a
```

You can then use the metavariables to launch with your sas command.